# Node.js explain Errors in REPL?

Tags: node.js, save, read-eval-print-loop

I tried this

```
.save myShell.js
```

that is followed by this error:

```
Failed to save:myShell.js
```

why do I get this error ?

Comment: Do you have write access to the directory in which you are executing REPL?

Comment: I install it on windows as a msi package,I guess I own all rights and have absolute access to all locations on my system.

Comment: How can I test it, if I have write access for nodejs on my windows system?

Answer (score 0):

I save the situation with the start of the node.js command promt.
By windows install you get (so was after install on my sys) some several shortcuts , one with the node.js icon and it's name ist Node.js and another that is called Node.js command promt - if you want to use the .save command to save the session you must to run the "Node.js command prompt". 
Of  course with some more work you can get more.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions issue.

2 options:

- Run "Node.js" app as administrator (right click on the icon in the start menu "run as admin"
- Run "Node.js Command Prompt" app and then type "node" which will put you in REPL